# ASP.NET Core MVC Post collection is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET Core MVC using EF Core 6, I have the following problem:

`[HttpPost] Create()` gets the applicant object (Master) correctly,
but `applicant.Experiences` (detail) is empty. Maybe I missed something in binding detail?

I use "EF Core Power Tools" to generate the model.

Thanks for your help.

Controller:

```
public class ResumeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        Applicant applicant = new Applicant();
        applicant.Experiences.Add (new Experience() { ExperienceId = 1 });
        applicant.Experiences.Add(new Experience() { ExperienceId = 2 });
        applicant.Experiences.Add(new Experience() { ExperienceId = 3 });
        return View(applicant);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(Applicant applicant)
    {
       //***********Error***************
       //applicant.Experiences.count = 0 , Should be 3
       //********************************
        _context.Add(applicant);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Model classes:

```
public partial class Applicant
{
    public Applicant()
    {
        Experiences = new List<Experience>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Experience> Experiences { get; set; }
}

public partial class Experience
{
    public int ExperienceId { get; set; }
    public int ApplicantId { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public virtual Applicant Applicant { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Experiences.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Experiences[i].FieldName, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is outside of the posted form so it will not be included in the form data posted. Move it inside the `form` tag (and adjust the html accordingly).

P.S.

In general try avoiding using Entity Framework entities as models, create special DTOs and map between them, this will solve quite a lot of issues, including [overposting attacks](https://andrewlock.net/preventing-mass-assignment-or-over-posting-in-asp-net-core/).

Comment: now `applicant.Experiences.count = 3` after posting which is correct but
`context.SaveChanges();` raise exception:
`System.InvalidOperationException:` 'The instance of entity type 'Experience' cannot be tracked because another instance 
with the same key value for {'ExperienceId'} is already being tracked. 

i notice that in `_context.Add(applicant);` applicant.experience[0,1,2].experienceId = 0 although when i add it, it has values of 1,2,3 
also applicant.experience[0,1,2].applicantId (FK) = 0 although applicant.id = 6.
why binding /EF is not work as expected?

Comment: @shadyfady as for the EF - it is another question and it works as expected in this case. Feel free to post another question or wait around an hour - I will find answer with explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  You r right, I think it is better to ask another question.